# How to restrict some web service methods to some users?

Tags: java, web-services

My question is, i have a web service written in Java and i want to give specific authorizations to users, for example, userA should access only methodA, userB should access only methodB. How can i do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: With some kind of authentication and a permission system? Like a login, for example...

Comment: What server are you using?  Are you using Spring?

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. What framework(s) are you using? What is the structure of your application (is it a web app)? What version of JEE, if applicable? How are you identifying users?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest and most standardized way of doing this is with spring security, I find it pretty easy to use, read more about it here: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/

And if you don't want it for some reason, a javax.servlet.Filter is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder that, with this way, will users be able to see the restricted method, how does it work?

Comment: Have you implemented any of spring already?  It's generally used with SpringMVC.

Comment: @emre you can refer to the link that I provided in my initial post, if an user that is not logged in tries to access a restricted/protected URL it is redirected to a login page provided by spring-security (it is provided by spring-security by default, you don't have to do anything), if he is logged in but doesn't have the permission to access that URL, he will see an 403 page or something similar.

Comment: @david99world I don't think I fully understand your question. Yes, spring security is used most times with spring-mvc, this is how I used it and worked very well, but I am sure you could use it with any web application.

Comment: Ah, I was only interested if OP had already used Spring, it really depends on his implementation.  I just thought the learning curve of having to learn Spring could be a pain if he'd never used it before, but I've only ever used Spring Security within SpringMVC (although you're quire right, about not requiring it :) )

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of ways, this depends entirely on your deployment.  But just as a shot in the dark, you can restrict this in your web.xml.

Create a security constraint in the web.xml...

```
 <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>MRC Customer Care</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                    <role-name>role1</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Then, map this role (role1) to a user...

```
<tomcat-users>
  <user name="role1"  password="tomcat" roles="role1"  />
</tomcat-users>
```

Valid users will be able to get to your URI at /protected/ assuming that's where your web service is, invalid users will receive a 403.

This is one potential answer.